# Why does some of my animation get missed?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, animation, triggers

I have some animation that runs on loaded event of window. Problem is when the window actually loads some of my animation is already missed. I see my animation from halfway through. The animation lasts for 0.7 seconds. This is my code:

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="FrameworkElement.Loaded">
        <BeginStoryboard Storyboard="{StaticResource storyboardMenu}"/>
    </EventTrigger>
</Window.Triggers>
```

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impossible to say without knowing more but my guess is something else is happening in or after the loaded event firing which is delaying the window becoming visible.  Binding a large amount of data is a possible cause.  An async call being started in your constructor or loaded events might be returning really quickly and blocking the UI thread for a few milliseconds before the windows can be displayed possibly?

Comment: You are correct. Large amount of data is returned. So what can be done about this? or rather can anything be done about this?

Comment: There are things you can do, although it depends on where that data is coming from and how you are fetching it.  Firstly are you loading the data asynchronously?  If not that might help.  Another option is to chunk or page the data as it comes back on a timer.  So load 50-100 items every 10msec until it's all loaded.

Comment: Another thing is to check your ListBoxes are still virtualized.  They are by default but if you have changed the ListBox's ItemPanel template to something other than VirtualizingStackPanel they might not be anymore.

Also check out http://www.kirupa.com/net/ui_virtualization_pg2.htm for more info on virtualizing the UI.